# numpy take can't index using slice

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

According to the numpy docs for [`take`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take.html)
it does the same thing as “fancy” indexing (indexing arrays using arrays). However, it can be easier to use if you need elements along a given axis.

However, unlike "fancy" or regular numpy indexing, using slices as indices appears to be not supported:

```
In [319]: A = np.arange(20).reshape(4, 5)

In [320]: A[..., 1:4]
Out[320]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [11, 12, 13],
       [16, 17, 18]])

In [321]: np.take(A, slice(1, 4), axis=-1)
TypeError: long() argument must be a string or a number, not 'slice'
```

What is the best way to index an array using slices along an axis only known at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> According to the numpy docs for take it does the same thing as “fancy” indexing (indexing arrays **using arrays**).

The second argument to `np.take` has to be *array-like* (an array, a list, a tuple etc.), not a `slice` object. You could construct an indexing array or list that does your desired slicing:

```
a = np.arange(24).reshape(2, 3, 4)

np.take(a, slice(1, 4, 2), 2)
# TypeError: long() argument must be a string or a number, not 'slice'

np.take(a, range(1, 4, 2), 2)
# array([[[ 1,  3],
#         [ 5,  7],
#         [ 9, 11]],

#        [[13, 15],
#         [17, 19],
#         [21, 23]]])
```

> What is the best way to index an array using slices along an axis only known at runtime?

What I often prefer do is to use [`np.rollaxis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rollaxis.html) to make the axis to be indexed into the first one, do my indexing, then roll it back into its original position.

For example, let's say I want odd-numbered slices of a 3D array along its 3rd axis:

```
sliced1 = a[:, :, 1::2]
```

If I then wanted to specify the axis to slice along at runtime, I could do it like this:

```
n = 2    # axis to slice along

sliced2 = np.rollaxis(np.rollaxis(a, n, 0)[1::2], 0, n + 1)

assert np.all(sliced1 == sliced2)
```

To unpack that one-liner a bit:

```
# roll the nth axis to the 0th position
np.rollaxis(a, n, 0)

# index odd-numbered slices along the 0th axis
np.rollaxis(a, n, 0)[1::2]

# roll the 0th axis back so that it lies before position n + 1 (note the '+ 1'!)
np.rollaxis(np.rollaxis(a, n, 0)[1::2], 0, n + 1)
```

Comment: From the `np.rollaxis` [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rollaxis.html): "This function continues to be supported for backward compatibility, but you should prefer moveaxis. The moveaxis function was added in NumPy 1.11." If you use `np.moveaxis` instead, you don't need to add the confusing `+1` in your answer.

Answer (score 5):

The most efficient method seems to be `A[(slice(None),) * axis + (slice(1, 4),)]`:

```
In [19]: import numpy as np
    ...: x = np.random.normal(0, 1, (50, 50, 50))
    ...: s = slice(10, 20)
    ...: axis = 2
    ...: 
    ...: 

In [20]: timeit np.rollaxis(np.rollaxis(x, axis, 0)[s], 0, axis + 1)
2.32 µs ± 15.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [21]: timeit x.take(np.arange(x.shape[axis])[s], axis)
28.5 µs ± 38.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [22]: timeit x[(slice(None),) * axis + (s,)]
321 ns ± 0.341 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Comment: That's a clever way to programmatically use `__getitem__`

Comment: Great solution. Can you add `axis = axis % x.ndim` to normalize the axis argument? Then also negative values for axis do the correct thing.

Answer (score 4):

I take it that you mean:

```
In [566]: np.take(A, slice(1,4))
...
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'slice'
```

But

```
np.take(A, np.r_[1:4])
```

works just like `A[1:4]`

Functions like `np.insert` and `np.apply_along_axis` achieve generality by constructing indexing tuples that may include scalars, slices, and arrays.

```
ind = tuple([slice(1,4)])  # ndim terms to match array
A[ind]
```

`np.tensordot` is an example of using `np.transpose` to move action axes to the end (for use by `np.dot`).

Another trick is to collapse all 'surplus' axes to one with a reshape.  And then reshape back after.

Comment: Using `np.r_` is a nice compact solution. However remember to replace `None` for stop indices with `A.shape[axis]`; and correspondingly dealing with negative indices.